# Can I Upgrade to 11.10 on my PPC 10.04?

Tags: 11.10, ppc

I have 10.04 installed on my MacMini PowerPC, I was thinking about upgrading to 11.10, can I do this through an update or do I have to find and download a community supported iso file?

Comment: /!\ This questions implies "Can I upgrade to 11.10 knowing that no community support is given for 11.04 nor 11.10?"

Comment: oh I thought it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to reinstall everything using a 11.10 iso CD, you will have to upgrade to each version, 10.10, 11.04 and then 11.10 from the update center.

PS: do this quickly as 10.04 is LTS so its end of life is april 2013 (for desktop) but 10.10 is not and will end in april 2012

Comment: so I can just use upgrade? from the update center?

Comment: yes, 3 times in your case

Comment: it seems a little slower with 11.04 won't let me use unity, I'm upgrading to 11.10 now.
I heard [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Which_Macs_are_compatible_with_Ubuntu.3F) that I should use lubuntu or xubuntu?

Comment: I don't know MacMini specs but if you are short on RAM and not very fast CPU or graphic adapter, maybe Unity will be a little heavy but I use it on old machines and it is not THAT slow with 2GB RAM on an ATHLON 1800... 10 years old machine. Of course on the other machines I use it (dual core machines and i5) it is a lot faster... maybe lubuntu or xubuntu better and faster but I've never used them (yet).